# Run a Macro present in an Addin when called from a CommandButton on Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro defined in an AddIn file when existing Commandbutton on an excel sheet is clicked. Excel sheet is XLSX file and **NOT XLSM**.

I already have command buttons on sheet (XLSX file) and I dont want to add any buttons or change file format to XLSM.

I dont want to write any code in sheet module of XLSX file as anyway it wont be saved when I close the file.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Form Control CommandButton to your sheet. When you click Assign Macro, it won't be on the list but if you type in ProjectName.ModuleName.MacroName, it will run when you click the button.

For example, I have an add-in "DSObjectAddIn.xla". It's project is named `DS`. I create a button and assign the macro: `DS.mDSO.InitAll`.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have 30 different XLSX files with each having commandbuttons existing already. Now I want to manage all of them with this single Add-in. Opening each of 30 sheets and assigning macro to each button consumes lot of time...so please reply with a solution.